# Mazda 3 speedometer not functioning

Tags: manual-transmission, power-steering, mazda-3, speedometer, vehicle-speed-sensor

I have a 2004 Mazda 3 manual transmission that I purchased recently. The speedometer and of course the odometer are not functioning. I have checked to see if I would be able to replace a vehicle speed sensor but I can't locate anything that looks like that sensor on the vehicle. I did check all the fuses and they seem to be fine. Also, this might be entirely unrelated but the power steering doesn't seem to do as much as it should. It definitely does something but steering fast is hard. Can somebody confirm, does the manual transmission have a speed sensor on the transmission somewhere? Or what other things could I check to get the speedometer to work again?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten about this for some time. I've been driving with a functioning speedo for some time now. Simply replaced the ABS sensor and got my speedo back. As a bonus I also got my power steering functioning properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the battery duct and cover and possibly the battery and tray to access it.

[image]